# WPF AutoCompleteBox Style DataTemplate Bind ValueMemberPath To Content

Tags: wpf, bind, datatemplate

So I have an

```
<controls:AutoCompleteBox ItemsSource="{Binding Nationalities}" SelectedItem="{Binding IDIssueCountry, Mode=TwoWay}" ValueMemberPath="NationalityName"/>
```

And a style for itemtemplate that i want its content bound to ValueMemberPath's value:

```
<Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{What Binding to put here to get ValueMemberPath's value}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
```

Thanks in advance

P.S: TemplateBinding does not find ValueMemberPath..

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
<Label Content="{Binding NationalityName}"/>
```

Should work assuming that `NationalityName` is a property of an item in the `Nationalities` collection.

Note that you cannot bind the `Content` property of the `Label` to the property whose name is specified by the `ValueMemberPath` if that's what you are trying to do.

The value of the `ValueMemberPath` is used internally by the control to get the value of the underlying data object using reflection.

Comment: Yes but this style is used by default and it will have different items, for example companies is with other Name. That is why I want to get the ValueMemberPath's value

Comment: There is no way to bind to the property *whose name* is specified by the ValueMemberPath property in pure XAML. You need to specify the name of the *property* to bind to. You cannot specify the name of the property that holds the name of the property to bind to. So this is not possible I am afraid.